# Webpack dist folder not getting created in project folder?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

Everything running fine, but could not able to find where is my dist folder.I am using publicPath as per documentation, still dist folder seems to coming from memory.

This might be small issue, i am new to webpack. Any help would work

Below is my webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath:'/dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats:'error-only'
    }
};
```

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "tryout",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha './tests/**/*.test.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "start-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --content-base dist/ --port 6969",
    "s": "npm run start-dev-server",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.4.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "nock": "^8.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.1.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: “publicPath” is used by several Webpack’s plugins to update the URLs inside CSS, HTML files when generating production builds. Therefore it won't have any affect on your dev environment https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9#.1j9bauc10

Comment: I am able to create dist folder on local by webpack -p. But this will not work on local because it only create distribution code does not happens with server start and pointer to dist folder. Can this be achieve on local machine ?

Answer (score 44):

> still dist folder seems to coming from memory

Most likely because you're using `webpack-dev-server` (that's what it does).

If you want your bundled assets to be actually written to disk, run `webpack`.

Comment: grt this work !! solves my confusion.  CLI gets exit after creating dist folder on disck dont seves on localhost:port-number. Any ref about how to run app from dist folder like prod on local

Comment: @PradeepJaiswar it depends on your app, it might work with something as simple as [`http-server`](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `devServer:{ writeToDisk: true }` is no longer supported

The recent solution is to add  `"build": "webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js"` to your `package.json`. Ensure your webpack config `output` params are set as

`output: {filename: "[name].bundle.js", path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"), publicPath: ""}`

Now go to your terminal and run `npm run build`. Voila!. Your `dist` folder should appear in your project directory.

Cheers!