# push assets folder to public directory with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm using Webpack for the first time. Currently everything is being served up quite nicely. My problem is when I'm trying to build a `dist` folder. Currently I get my `index.html` and `bundle.js` files but I can't figure out how to push my assets to the `dist` folder.

I have file-loader loaded up but it doesn't actually seem to do what I want it to and none of the google searches I've run are telling me what I need to know. Below is my config file. Can someone lead a horse to water? Also once I get it running do I need to import all of images to my React components?

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]},
      { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|)$/, use: { loader: 'file-loader', options: }}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Try `PublicPath:/dist` in module.exports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277673/webpack-dist-folder-not-getting-created-in-project-folder

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to use [Copy-Webpack-Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin).

To copy all the assets from 'app/assets/' to 'dist/assets/' I just needed to do:

```
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'app/assets', to: 'assets' }
    ])
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

First install copy webpack plugin:

```
npm i copy-webpack-plugin
```

Then in the webpack.config.json:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "src/public", to: "" } //to the dist root directory
            ],
        }),
    ],
};
```