# Webpack not able to find public folder on Production Build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, react-16

My current folder structure

```
- app
- build
- public
  - simulation
    - index.html
- server
```

I have a .html file in the public > simulation folder.

and I am opening this HTML file in an iFrame inside a React component

```
export default function B2BSalesSimulation(props) {
    return (<>
        <iframe title='mytitle' src={`${props.baseURl}/simulation/index.html`} width='100%' height='800px'>
            Your browser does not support simulation
        </iframe>
    </>)
}
```

When I run the code locally I am able to view the index file inside the iFRAME. No special routing is provided.

But when I deploy it to the server [ Build running on nginx server ]. It shows Page not found inside the iFRAME.

Snapshot on local
[image: Local]

Snapshot on server

[image]

The URL of the iframe is the same in both cases only the host changes.

Webpack config:

```
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = options => ({
  mode: options.mode,
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign(
    {
      // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    options.output,
  ), // Merge with env dependent settings
  optimization: options.optimization,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // Transform all .js and .jsx files required somewhere with Babel
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: options.babelQuery,
        },
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                enabled: false,
                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                // enabled: true,
                // progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; Terser will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
      RAZORPAY_KEY: 'XXXXXXX',
    }),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'app'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

Comment: Can you inspect the build assets? Do they contain your public folder? If not, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578665/push-assets-folder-to-public-directory-with-webpack

Comment: Is the file where your nginx server expects to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed to use Copy-Webpack-Plugin.

First installed the package

```
npm i copy-webpack-plugin
```

To copy all the assets from 'app/public/simulation' to 'dist/simulation' I just needed to add into my webpack config file:

```
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'app/public/simulation', to: 'simulation' }
    ])
  ]
```